# Creating varied socket responses in Python

Tags: python, sockets

The code below creates a socket server. I want the server to respond depending on what the user inputs. In this case, if it is equal to y, a different message is produced. How can I edit the existing code to make this work?

```
import socketserver

class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        y = 100
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print("{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0]))
        print(self.data)

        if self.data == y:

            self.request.sendall(self.data, "is correct")
        else:
            self.request.sendall("incorrect")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999

    # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9999
    with socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler) as server:
        # Activate the server; this will keep running until you
        # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
        server.serve_forever()
```

---

EDIT:
I have edited the code as follows:

```
class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        k = 500
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print("{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0]))
        print(self.data)
        if int(self.data) == k:
            self.request.sendall((self.data), b"is correct")
        else:
            self.request.sendall(b"incorrect")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999

    # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9999
    with socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler) as server:
        server.serve_forever()
```

if a value is 'incorrect' it outputs "incorrect" as it should. However if the value of k is the same as what the user inputs, an error is thrown: 'an integer is required  (got type bytes).
I have tried editing parts of the code but have not yet been able to get round this. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: The data received from the client will be in the form of a bytestring.  It will *never* be equal to 100, or any other integer.

Comment: is there not a way to convert the bytestring to an integer upon reception?

Comment: @jasonharper ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is byte string, therefore you need to convert it to int before doing comparison, try to replace:

```
if self.data == y:
    ...
```

to

```
if int(self.data) == y:
    ...
```

Comment: Any more tips? @Andriy-Ivaneyko